# What do short names / verbs like <leader>, <C-r> mean in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax

I'm using Vim for a while now, starting to like it more and more. But when searching for some new features that Vim has in it's goodie bag, I'm often slapped in the face with things like `<Leader>` `<C-r>`, etc... I'm feeling really stupid for not being able to relate these to keys, commands, or what soever they should mean. I've also been searching multiple times for the use of these verbs, but I think I'm not using the correct search queries to get to the right explanation pages.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction or maybe summarize the meaning / workings of these verbs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`:help key-notation` lists the meanings of all those `<key>`.

Answer (score 2):

Mhhh .. among the first results in google for "vim leader" this pops up:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764263/what-is-the-leader-in-a-vimrc-file

`<C-r>` is some mapping to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> key-combination, whatever that maps to. You just enter `:help c-r` and press tab to get the list of help topics.

Comment: Feeling even more stupid now... Thanks, I can't even imagine how I would not have found that... I did not know about the `:help c-r` for help on shortcuts, thanks!

Comment: `c-r` itself is most likely a `mapping`, fire `:map` or `:vmap` or `:imap` to see whats behind it.

Comment: `help c-r` took me to `<C-Right`, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Flimm: `the same thing` as … what? the question was how to find information about key-combos like `x`. using :help is one way, using :*map to check current mappings to the actual function being called is another.

Comment: ctrl-r is not the same thing as ctrl-right